# Insertion of SQL Query result into a BLOB Column in Oracle APEX and exposing the column for downloading

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have a requirement where-in the ask is, To build a report which ideally can store a SQL query result into a BLOB column. And exposing the BLOB column to the end-users, so that they would be able to download the same.
Oracle APEX version used is Application Express 4.0.2.00.07

Comment: What have you tried thus far?

Comment: Tried following few blogs, but most of them had the upload file feature present in them. Wasn't able to by-pass that. Since in my case, I needed the query output, to be stored In a BLOB column of a table. :( And then making the BLOB column visible to the users as a hyperlink, from which they could download the report.

Answer (score 0):

In Apex (OK, *Oracle Application Express*), a "query result" is result of a classic or interactive report. Both of them have an option to download the result in various formats, where CSV seems to be quite appropriate.

I'd suggest you to check how it works.

Because, from my point of view, storing textual information (that's what query most usually returns) into a BLOB column (why **binary** large object? What's *binary* in that output? Why not CLOB?) is kind of an overkill which unnecessarily complicates things.

If your users download a CSV, they can easily open it in Excel which is something that users love very much, and then do various things with information they see.

Comment: Yeah the problem with a direct download is that my records are getting limited to a few lakhs. I have data resulting in more that a million. And when we download the same, it downloads partially only. Hence thought of the CLOB approach.

Comment: I see; well, note that CLOB (or BLOB) isn't unlimited in size either.

Comment: What would the best approach be, in case I have to download a large data-set then ? Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps creating a file (using UTL_FILE package), which is then limited only by free disk space.

Comment: The UTL_file actually worked.. can store data upto 3-4gb. Thank you.